# Persistence Hibernate updating of table java

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jakarta-ee, persistence

I have a java EE project with persistence Hibernate that has a view that is showing several fields with values that are pulled from the database. Now when I put a new value in the field and click save I want it to update it to the database.

What I tried.

```
public static void updateDB(Object o) {
        Session dbSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            Transaction tx = dbSession.beginTransaction();
            dbSession.update(o);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException he) {
        } finally {
            dbSession.clear();
            dbSession.close();
        }
    }



 @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        UserInfo userinfo = new UserInfo();

        if (request.getParameter("save0") != null) {
            userinfo.setPhone(request.getParameter("phoneNumber"));
            userinfo.setInterests(request.getParameter("interests"));
            updateDB(userinfo);
        } 

        redirect(request, response);

    }
```

The save0 is the name of the button to save the details.

Form:

```
<form name="create" action="Edit?view=0" method="post" autocomplete="off" >
```

Button:

```
 <div class="ui fluid black submit button" name="save0" onclick="document.create.submit()">Save</div>
```

And the view=0 is the view that gets the values from the database through the servlet.

Comment: What's your question? Why do you ignore exceptions?

Comment: Then what is the problem? write he.printStackTrace() in catch block to know more about it.

Comment: i really confuse that what is your actual question is. just have exception catch block and trace exception. and or if u need more help then paste your exception block here.